# What are other sources of screen tearing?

Tags: directx, directx11, gpu

I have a DirectX11 based engine / application that is showing screen tearing on a certain system.  The system has a large TV monitor with a GTX 980 graphics card.  The tearing tends to happen in roughly the same spot on the screen when the camera / eyepoint is moving around.  If we change settings (e.g. turn Ambient occlusion on ) then the tearing might move to a different location but it is still consistent.  Our statistics show that application is running at 60Hz and vsync is turned on in the application.  We also have an OpenGL based version of the application that doesn't exhibit this problem.

Things we've tried:

- Force vsync on in nvidia's control panel
- Turn on triple buffering on in nvidia's control panel
- Updated the nvidia driver
- Changed the monitor's refresh rate (tried 60, 59, and 24 hz)

None of these changes have changed screen tearing behavior.
What are other sources of screen tearing and how can they be addressed?

Update:

This computer is using windows 7 but doesn't have windows aero enabled (its using a classic theme).  On another computer, that didn't initially have any tearing problems, turning off windows aero makes screen tearing occur in the application.

Comment: Do you have more than one display connected to the machine?

Comment: Yes, there are two displays.

Comment: Does the screen tearing appear on screenshots?

Comment: Just took several screenshots (using printscreen) and the tearing (which was visible on the montior) did not show up in any of the screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the problem was due to Windows Aero being turned off on the target machine.  According to the nvidia forum [here](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/481897/missing-feature-force-vsync-in-2d-applications-38-windows-desktop/), there is no way to enable vsync if windows aero is not enabled, so the only fix is to enable windows aero, which eliminates the screen tearing.

Comment: Why there was no tearing on OpenGL?

Comment: I read several places that indicated that windows aero used directx and/or was more tightly coupled to directx.  I found someone [here](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-Screen-Tearing-with-Directx-but-not-with-OpenGL) that had the same issue I had with directx but not opengl.  And the forum [here](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-Vsync-functionality-doesn-t-work-in-Aero-Basic) suggests that "OpenGl, being tied into your display driver, can actually do a better job...[with vysnc stuff]". I would guess that directx relys on windows aero for vsync but the opengl goes around aero.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu of your graphics card you can select wether to use the global standart or "internal". You have to select the global standart. Then you can also disable "Multi-Threading". These two steps solved the same problem for me on my new PC.

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you clarify exactly what steps I should take?

Comment: Does your application use 3D graphics?

Comment: Yes it is primarily a 3d application.

Comment: Do you know where to find the 3D render setting of your graphics card?

Comment: Yes i'm using nvidia's control panel as mentioned in the question

Comment: My confusion is I don't see anything about "global standart" (global standard?) or "internal" or "Multi-threading" in the control panel.

Comment: 1. You open the control panel and select something like 3D settings or something like this

Comment: I'm German so I don't know the exact names of the tabs

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are getting at.  Yes, when i tried forcing vsync on in the control panel, I made sure i was in the "global setting" and a set it to "on" instead of "use the 3d application setting".  I have not messed around with the multithreading settings as I'm not sure why that would help, and I need to use multithreading in our application uses directx multithreading for performance.

Comment: I mean: the second point is the preferred graphics processor. there are 3 options: global setting(normally also the nvidia crad), the ivdida card and integrated graphics card. you have to select the nvidia card